# Inner Join in Rails options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created below join query to fetch group name details.I am using below query in postgresql.

```sql
select DISTINCT e.group_id,e.groupname from user_group_table u, execution_groups e where (u.user_id=e.user_id or u.group_id=e.group_id) and u.user_id=12;
```

How to write above join query using "options_from_collection_for_select" in rails?

I have tried below code

```rb
user_groups = UserGroupTable.where(:user_id => id)

@execution_group_options =  ExecutionGroup.where(user_id: user_groups.select(:user_id)).or(ExecutionGroup.where(group_id: user_groups.select(:group_id)))
```

Getting below error

```rb
SELECT "execution_groups".* FROM "execution_groups" WHERE "execution_groups"."user_id" IN (SELECT "user_group_table"."user_id" FROM "user_group_table" WHERE "user_group_table"."user_id" = ?)  [["user_id", 6]]
"Threw an exception inside test.new() undefined method `or' for #<ExecutionGroup::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007faf9e10ee38>"
Threw an exception inside test.new() undefined method `or' for #<ExecutionGroup::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007faf9e10ee38>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start of by writing that query in the Rails query syntax.

I'll assume that `user_group_table` is available through the `UserGroup` model and `execution_groups` is available through the `ExecutionGroup` model.

```
# in controller
user_groups = UserGroup.where(user_id: 12)

@execution_group_options =
  ExecutionGroup.where(user_id: user_groups.select(:user_id))
  .or(ExecutionGroup.where(group_id: user_groups.select(:group_id)))
```

This produces the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT execution_groups.*
FROM execution_groups
WHERE
  execution_groups.user_id IN (
    SELECT user_group_table.user_id
    FROM user_group_table
    WHERE user_group_table.user_id = 12
  )
  OR
  execution_groups.group_id IN (
    SELECT user_group_table.group_id
    FROM user_group_table
    WHERE user_group_table.user_id = 12
  )
```

Which should produce the same collection (assuming there are no `ExecutionGroup` records that have the same `group_id` and `groupname`).

With the above in place you can use the following in your view:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@execution_group_options, 'group_id', 'groupname')
```

If there are `ExecutionGroup` records with both the same `group_id` and `groupname`. You can instead use:

```
options_for_select(@execution_group_options.distinct.pluck(:groupname, :group_id))
```

---

If you don't have access to [`or`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or) (introduced in Ruby on Rails 5), things become slightly more complicated. You should be able to use the internal [`arel`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel) interface.

```
# in controller
user_groups = UserGroup.where(user_id: 12)
exec_groups_table = ExecutionGroup.arel_table

@execution_group_options = ExecutionGroup.where(
  exec_groups_table[:user_id].in(user_groups.select(:user_id).arel)
  .or(exec_groups_table[:group_id].in(user_groups.select(:group_id).arel))
)
```

This should produce the exact same query. Other than the controller code nothing changes.

Comment: Thanks.I am getting below error.                                                                                          undefined method `or' for #<ExecutionGroup::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007faf9e10ee38>"

Comment: @User1984 What version of Rails are you using? The [`or`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or) method has been added in 5.0

Comment: I am using Rails 4.2.11.3

Comment: Working in old rails project which I couldn't upgrade rails

Comment: Can you please guide how to write code for this version?

Comment: Thanks for your effort.But I am getting below error

Comment: USER GROUPS--------------------12
"Threw an exception inside test.new() private method `select' called for \"12\":String"

Comment: @User1984 You should call `select` on the `UserGroup` ActiveRecord Relation. not on the string `"12"`. eg. `UserGroup.where(user_id: "12").select(:user_id)` **not** `"12".select(:user_id)`

Comment: user_groups = UserGroupTable.where(user_id: id)                                                                    
      execution_group_options = ExecutionGroup.where('execution_groups.user_id IN (:user_ids) OR execution_groups.group_id IN (:group_ids)',user_ids: user_groups.select(:user_id),group_ids: user_groups.select(:group_id))

Comment: "Threw an exception inside test.new() no implicit conversion of UserGroupTable::ActiveRecord_Relation into String"

Comment: Am I making any mistake? I am getting above error

Comment: id I am getting from below

Comment: user = User.find_by(name: session[:name])
      id = user.id.to_s

Comment: "Threw an exception inside test.new() no implicit conversion of ExecutionGroup::ActiveRecord_Relation into String"

Comment: This also I am getting

Comment: @User1984 Try adding `.to_sql` after `.select(...)`, which should convert the ActiveRecord Relation into a string. I've updated the answer with this as well.

Comment: No Luck."Threw an exception inside test.new() no implicit conversion of ExecutionGroup::ActiveRecord_Relation into String"

Comment: @User1984 Have you tried the arel solution?

Comment: yes I have added .to_sql.Getting same error